# Active Directory: Should Workstations be separated from servers to protect from related domain hacks?

Tags: web-application, windows, cookies, active-directory, same-origin-policy

How should I protect domain joined hosts in the same AD domain from the [Related Domain Cookie Attack](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/12419/396)?

Suppose there is an AD forest called `example.com`.  This company has a variety of internal and external web applications:

- store.example.com (customer facing)
- partnerPortal.example.com (internal/partner facing)
- payroll.example.com (internally facing)

The forest also has workstations on the same domain  `workstation001.example.com` ... etc.

Since this answer describes how [easy it is to alter cookies](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/12419/396), I think this is an opportunity for a [confused deputy issue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confused_deputy_problem), where the authority granted is the DNS name granted to the computer.

Would it be a security risk to have end users and servers under the same shared domain?  Keep in mind that most AD deployments fall into one of these configurations:

```
Forest/Domain Name     External DNS Name       Vulnerable to Related Domain Attack
Contoso.com            Contoso.com             Yes
AD.Contoso.com         Contoso.com             Yes                 
Contoso.Local          Contoso.com             No
```

What is the best way to mitigate this?

Comment: I cannot think of a single reason that payroll.example.com should be accessed outside of the network within an office.  Its only asking for trouble.

Comment: @Ramhound - It is very easy to substitute "payroll" with "shopping" or any other site the business considers high value.

Comment: Quite often payroll may be partially or fully outsourced so some type of sharing outside the network would be required.

Comment: @RoryAlsop To futher your point, more servers are being outsourced (Salesforce, etc), and the ability to inflict an attack is only getting larger and getting spread amongst more people/companies

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this has anything to do with Active Directory.  It is a question about internal web applications.

Yes, I imagine there is some security benefit to placing the internal apps on totally separate domains.  However, this may be annoying from a usability perspective (it may be more convenient for your users to have all the services under a single easy-to-remember domain name), and I'm not convinced that the usability hit is worth it, given that the security risks are probably modest.  In terms of resistance to internal attacks, I suspect at most sites there will be other more effective ways to harden yourself against internal/insider attacks.  But that's something you'll have to evaluate for yourself; it is a risk management exercise.

I don't know if there are better ways to mitigate the risk while maintaining the same domain name structure.  There may be ways to implement the critical webapps (e.g., `payroll.example.com`) in a way that limits the impact of those kind of attacks, but I just don't know what ways those might be, alas.  Sorry about that.

Comment: I don't see the risk limited to internal web applications.  I updated the question to describe deployments where external web applications are vulnerable as well...