# What issues might exist with TLS-OBC's emulation of Browser Certificates?

Tags: encryption, tls, web-browser, certificates, cookies

TLS-OBC is an RFC proposal that increases SSL/TLS security by using certificates on both ends of the TLS connection.  What's special here is that the client is permitted to dynamically create a local, self signed certificate.

It can also protect users from the ["Related Domain Cookie Attack"](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/12419/396), [more info here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9636857/328397)

Are there any known issues that would cause a problem with pre-existing Browser Certificate deployments and TLS-OBC?

- TLS-OBC for System Administrators: http://www.browserauth.net/
- TLS-OBC RFC: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-balfanz-tls-obc-01

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(TLS-OBC is not yet a RFC, just a proposal, and, as all drafts, can be subject to change.)

As presented, TLS-OBC is an extension to the [SSL/TLS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246) protocol. There is a scheme for such extensions, which can be added at the end of the `ClientHello` and `ServerHello` messages. Nothing related to TLS-OBC happens unless the client and then the server agree to use them. Possibly, some very old and buggy servers could choke on the `ClientHello` from the client, but the same can be said of every other extension and it does not prevent browsers from using, for instance, the [Server Name Indication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). So no real issue there.

Possible issues that I see with this draft include:

- When TLS-OBC is used, the server should not send a list of accepted CA, and the client MUST ignore them anyway. This means that a given server accepts either OBC-type certificates, or standard certificates, but not both. Moreover, the server must make this decision before knowing the target path, so it is a server-wide setting.
- The OBC is remarkably efficient at tracking clients -- that's its point, really, when it is used as a "strengthening of the cookie". This implies the same kind of privacy issues than cookies. I suppose that browsers implementing TLS-OBC will provide the same kind of choice than with cookies (i.e. a way to deny OBC usage with some specific servers).
- Contrary to normal client certificates, OBC do not prevent institutional Man-in-the-Middle attacks (when a proxy servers creates a fake server certificate on-the-fly -- this assumes that an accomplice CA is installed in the client trust store, which is a relatively common setup in some big organization which want to monitor their employees closely). The "attacker" (possibly a legitimate attacker, as a sysadmin) just has to substitute his own OBC.

Mostly, I do not see clearly in what way OBC really increases security.

Comment: Your points are valid except that, the third point regarding institutional man-in-the-middle attack isn't an issue with the draft because TLS OBC threat model doesn't cover attacker installing anything on client m/c i.e TLS OBC doesn't aim to solve that type of man-in-middle attack. This draft has now expired and in place a new draft TLS Channel IDs is in consideration.