# Is it possible to prevent attackers from destroying sessions using cookie tossing and cookie overflow attacks?

Tags: appsec, cookies

I won't really go into details of how cookie tossing and cookie overflow attacks work, because this [answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/12419/10147) explains it perfectly. This [post on github](https://github.com/blog/1466-yummy-cookies-across-domains) explains some mitigation strategies, but does not talk about the case where `a.domain.com` can do malicious things to `b.domain.com`.

The proposed solution is to host untrusted content on a second domain. For example, if we run `mycompany.com`, we should store user content on a second domain like `mycompany-users.com`.

Let's say we have this scenario: Our company provides a SaaS service for our customers. Each customer will be given their own URL to login and use the service. Customers are allowed to customize the look and feel of their instance by modifying the HTML, css and javascript of their pages.

In this case, we have `company1.mycompany-users.com` and `company2.mycompany-users.com`.

Let's say a malicious employee called Mallory at `company1` implements some javascript that uses a cookie tossing attack or a cookie jar overflow attack to set or replace the cookies on `.mycompany-users.com`.

An employee at `company2` is then tricked to visit that page on `company1.mycompany-users.com` and have their cookies on `.mycompany-users.com` replaced or modified.

Since the server does not receive the domain of the cookie, we cannot filter out cookies by their domains. Provided that the app is secure, the attacker cannot read or write to information on `company1.mycompany-users.com`. In addition, session ids are regenerated on login. However, it still annoys people because the session data is damaged and if the user is logged into `company2.mycompany-users.com` he would be logged out because the session id is invalid.

Besides forcing customers to buy their own domains, is there anyway to prevent malicious people at `company1.mycompany-users.com` to cause users at `company2.mycompany-users.com` to logout due to cookie attacks?

Comment: Where did you get the terms cookie tossing and cookie overflow?

Comment: @atk I have updated my question with the github post where these terms were used: https://github.com/blog/1466-yummy-cookies-across-domains

Comment: From the GitHub blog post, it sounds like they concluded that no, it is not possible to protect against this attack without giving every customer their own separate domain.

Comment: Basically, if untrusted JavaScript code can run on a sub or sibling domain of your domain, you *are* vulnerable to session fixation attacks, period. So... yeah. Thanks a lot browser vendors.

Comment: @F21 thanks for the links, though i dont know your answer but i could find answers for my questions in provided links ;) thanks man